# A subset of an infinite-dimensional simplex where no element is in the convex hull of other elements of the subset.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, simplex

Let

$$S=\{x\in R_{+}^\infty \mid \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=1\}$$

be an infinite simplex.

Suppose $\hat{S}$ is a countable subset of $S$ such that

1. for each $x\in \hat{S}$ only at most finitely many coordinates are non-zero, denote the set of those coordinates $N(x)$;
2. for any $x\neq x’$, $x, x’ \in \hat{S}$, $N(x)\neq N(x’)$.

How could one prove that no $x$ is in a convex hull of other elements of $\hat{S}$, i.e., no $x\in \hat{S}$ can be represented as a convex combination of other elements of $\hat{S}$?

**EDIT:** *Condition (2) should be read: "for any $x\neq x’$, $x, x’ \in \hat{S}$, $N(x)\triangle (\cup_{x'\in \hat{S}}N(x’)) \neq \emptyset$". Here $\triangle$ stands for a symmetric difference of sets.*

Thank you! (These two infinities intimidate me...)

Comment: What if $=\{(1,0,0,0,\ldots), (0,1,0,0,0\ldots), (\frac12,\frac12,0,0\ldots)\}$ ? It's countable, even finite, and the third is a convex combination of the first two... and their $N$-sets are all differrent.

Comment: Dear @HennoBrandsma thank you! Your example is very instructive as to what I was missing with my hypothesis. I have been thinking what I am actually after since then, does the following version of condition (2) work?: "For any $x$ and all $x'$ such that $x'\neq x$, $x' \in \hat{S}$, we have $\cup_{x'\in \hat{S}} N(x') \triangle N(x)\neq \emptyset$." ($\triangle$ = symmetric difference of sets). A less general version would be to require $N(x)\cap N(x')=\emptyset$, but it is too strong as a sufficient condition maybe... If you think that this can be a way to go, I am happy to amend my question.

Answer (score -2):

No countable set is convex [unless it is empty] (since in a convex set, an interval between two points is contained in the set, and an interval has uncountably many points. However, your statement after the i.e. has nothing to do with convexity.

Comment: The OP means another notion of "convex"...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma ??? "I would like to prove that $X$ is a triangle, where a triangle is a figure with five sides?" Does not work for me, sorry.

Comment: At least the OP specified his question, after the i.e.  So it was clear what was meant. Don't just read a title and react to that... It's tempting but not helpful, I'm afraid.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma As stated by the OP, the statement is false. There are plenty of examples where *some* $x$ can be written as $y+z.$ The OP probably means that **not all** $x$ can be so represented, but now we are firmly in mind-reading territory.

Comment: Dear @HennoBrandsma and Igor Rivin, I really did not mean to annoy anyone, I perfectly see now that I have misused the word "convex", what I meant is that no $x$ is  in a convex hull of other $x'\neq x$, $x'\in \hat{S}$, but the shortcut of "convex" was so attractive... My fault, again all my apologies, I will amend my question for that!